# WCF Catch Asynch Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, exception, asynchronous

I have a situation I'm looking for advice on.

I have a WCF service where in some of the methods I create an object that in turn establishes a socket connection to a server. I "cache" these connection objects in a dictionary object that's "global" to my service class. Once these connections are established there is a timer associated with each of them and the timer callback sends a keep-alive message to the server at regular intervals.

The problem comes if for whatever reason the server connection gets broken. When that happens I get an unhandled exception that seems to kill the WCF service.

I am hoping there's a way I can catch these timer related exceptions and simply close the socket and remove the connection object from the cache but I'm not sure there is a way. It would seem once I leave the method that uses the connection object there's nothing to catch the asynchronous exception.

Comment: Can you post some more information about the exception and maybe the timer code that send the keep-alive messages? How are you connecting to the server? Can you show us the the code that sets up you connection?

Comment: Some of your methods in your service seem to be long-lived and long-running -- are you sure this is a good design?  And is this a singleton service?

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop some kind of connection manager, that holds and monitor the state of each connection. the keep-alive timer is good for state tracking but you still need to check that a connection is valid before using it.

in any case, getting exception when using a faulted connection should not result in an unhandeled exception from the WCF service, you should wrap the access to the connection manager in a try-catch clauses.

Cheers,

Gilad

Comment: I'm wondering if I could add an event to the objects that manage the connection such that if they catch an exception when sending they can trigger an event. The "manager" object would have an event handler that could remove the connection object from the cache when the event is triggered.